# Help me make a waterfall

Tags: fluid-simulation

It has been 3 days now, countless YT tutorials, new and old, searchign on Blender Stackexchange and I just can't make it work.

Additional info: I understand the basic concpets and the objects needed for a fluid simulation to be successful.

I have carved out the environment with sculpting on a Plane where the water should be, and my next step would have been adding the water. As I am a beginner I think I tried everything with the Fluid simulation, it works fine when I start from scratch on a clean Blender, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to make it work in the this case. Please give me pointers on how to make this happen, cuz I'm starting to lose my mind :D

Thank you!

PS in the meantim I am tryign to figure out how to add the .blend file :D

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eX-lgrwlHWk5Zotr76cX3adGtFFshJdq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is it supposed to be realistic?

Comment: Well it is not important, but if you want to advise that I make the water out of Planes, with noise and shading and so on, I would like to avoid that, and actually learn how to use the fluid animation in any scenario :)

Comment: it looks like a guy called Olav likes water simulations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIxUZpRk4Ac   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOtZdysaJEA

Comment: Thanks moonboots, as I said in the very first row, I have been through these tutorials, step by step, I understand what does what, I followed the steps the same way here and apparently I am still doing something wrong. 

btw the blender file is attached (blender exchange doesnt seem to work)

Comment: You can upload .blend files at blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com . If you want to know more about why this is the preferred method here, please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please)

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For a fluid simulator like the one you want to create **you need**:

- emitter: the mesh where water comes from (choose flow > liquid & inflow)
- effector > collision: the mesh that will act as the collision terrain
- domain: it's the area where the simulation should run. Emitter and Effector should be inside the domain

The **core steps** to create the simulation are:

1. Put all the stuff in place
2. select the Domain and press the CACHE button
3. play the animation and check if everything is ok
4. select the domain, goto Mesh, select it and CACHE MESH
5. check result and goto 1 to fix settings if you are not happy with the result
6. apply shader and similar...

here's what I have to share:

[image]
here's the source file of my simulation (you need to cache):
https://pasteall.org/blend/5ff62299dac24ba7adec6d04e350173c

Comment: Thank you, but it won't work sadly :(

The steps I have taken are exactly the same:

1) I have the Plane which had the Effector (collision) mode
2) I add the Cube that contains the whole of the plain and acts as the Domain
3) I add a UV Sphere to be the Emitter (Flow mode)
4) I bake the data and nothing happens

I understand the basic concept how the fluid system works and what elements you need for it to work. 

I have been playing around with the Fluid concept on a blank canvas and it worked with everything else (big cube as domain, multiple small cubes or planes for collision)

Comment: check shared .blend file (it seems that in your blend file the problem is the terrain mesh, try to simplify and start from a cube - not a plane).

Comment: I will remake the environment from a cube tomorrow and let you know how it works.

I didn't think it was an issue with the plane, as when I played around with the fluid animation, I used planes as levels (so that it would act liek the one you jsut sent) and it worked fine.

I'll let you know how it goes ASAP

thanks

Comment: Good news, the preminilary testing proves that it should work, I made a quick environment out of a cube, carved it up a bit with sculpting and it seems to be working great :D all in all thanks for the advice, really not sure why I had this issue with the Plane to be honest, but regardless, thanks!

Comment: there are some specific settings for having a plane as a collision mesh (my tests also failed..)

Comment: Other than the accidental penis shape, it finally works... https://pasteall.org/pic/247c644027ec4cea9ca59757f0bb5b0e

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O0QcLpAxV4
How to fix the Planes and Circles fluid and some other things